# SyncFusion flutter onMarkerRender callback not getting triggered

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I'm trying to render some charts by using **syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.3.47** library in flutter. But I have an issue that the **onMarkerRender** callback function is not getting triggered. Below is my code, I have tried debug with break point and print statements. Unfortunately, nothing is working.

```
SfCartesianChart(
                  onMarkerRender: (MarkerRenderArgs args) {
                    print(args);
                    ChartData dataPoint = lineChartData[args.pointIndex ?? 0];
                    if ((dataPoint.inns1Wkt && args.seriesIndex == 1) ||
                        (dataPoint.inns2Wkt && args.seriesIndex == 2)) {
                      args.color =
                          args.seriesIndex == 1 ? Colors.red : Colors.amber;
                      args.markerHeight = 10;
                      args.markerWidth = 10;
                    } else {
                      args.markerHeight = 0;
                      args.markerWidth = 0;
                    }
                  },
                  legend: Legend(
                    isVisible: true,
                    position: LegendPosition.bottom,
                  ),
                  title: ChartTitle(
                    textStyle: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .subtitle2
                        ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    text: 'comparision',
                  ),
                  trackballBehavior: _trackballBehavior1,
                  series: <LineSeries<ChartData, num>>[
                    LineSeries<ChartData, num>(
                        name: widget.match.summary!.inns1.battingTeam!.name,
                        animationDuration: 1500,
                        dataSource: lineChartData,
                        xValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) => sales.over,
                        yValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) =>
                            sales.inns1TotalRun,
                        markerSettings: MarkerSettings(isVisible: true),
                        emptyPointSettings: EmptyPointSettings(
                            // Mode of empty point
                            mode: EmptyPointMode.gap)),
                    LineSeries<ChartData, num>(
                        animationDuration: 1500,
                        name: widget.match.summary!.inns2.battingTeam!.name,
                        dataSource: lineChartData,
                        xValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) => sales.over,
                        yValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) =>
                            sales.inns2TotalRun,
                        dataLabelMapper: (ChartData sales, _) =>
                            '${sales.over}',
                        markerSettings: MarkerSettings(
                          isVisible: true,
                        ),
                        emptyPointSettings:
                            EmptyPointSettings(mode: EmptyPointMode.gap)),
                  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The onMarkerRender callback is getting triggered properly with the latest version. Ensure you use the latest version of chart package.

Version: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/versions/19.3.48

Comment: I have tested with version 19.3.54 and it is working fine. Thank you